# Matplotlib draw_artist(axis.patch) fails on MacOSX backend

Tags: macos, python-3.x, matplotlib, runtime-error

I was following [Speeding up Matplotlib -- Bastibe](http://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html) to test making animation by only updating what has changed in the figure. And I'm using Mac OS X 10.11.4, Python 3.4 installed by MacPorts. The code looks like:

```
'''Import modules'''
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

'''Initialize figure and axis, perform first draw on canvas'''
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(np.random.randn(100))
plt.show(block=False)
fig.canvas.draw()

'''Count how many plots made within 1 second'''
tstart = time.time()
num_plots = 0
while time.time()-tstart < 1:            # within 1 second
    line.set_ydata(np.random.randn(100)) # update line
    ax.draw_artist(ax.patch)             # draw background
    ax.draw_artist(line)                 # draw line
    fig.canvas.update()                  # update canvas
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    num_plots += 1                       # count++
print(num_plots)
```

This code works fine on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4 + Qt5Agg backend. But on Mac, it reports

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 19, in <module>
    ax.draw_artist(ax.patch)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2340, in draw_artist
    a.draw(self._cachedRenderer)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 486, in draw
    gc = renderer.new_gc()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 99, in new_gc
    self.gc.save()
RuntimeError: CGContextRef is NULL
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different backend.
Add these lines to the very beginning of your script:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
```

This gives me 283 plots, whereas `fig.canvas.draw()` only gives 26 plots.

Comment: Good advice Mike. The kernel must be restarted otherwise matplotlib complains that `matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')` has no effect because the backend has already been chosen. You will also need to close the plot `plt.close()` or it will hang there.

Comment: Thank you for this. In fact I know Qt backend works, though I still want to know what is wrong with the original MacOSX backend. Or should I ask if there is some advantage of using Qt backend instead of the original one?